# What "concept" is invariant through a coordinate transformation here?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-geometry, projective-space

I am reading Kunz's "Introduction to Commutative Algebra and Algebraic Geometry" and I'm not understanding what is meant by the underlined sentence in the screenshot below. What exactly is invariant here?
If $T: \mathbb{P}^n \to \mathbb{P}^n$ is the corresponding coordinate transformation, do we have $T(V) = V$ for any projective variety $V \subset \mathbb{P}^n$? I don't think so because if I take $V = V(x^2 + y^2 -xy) \subset \mathbb{P}^2(\mathbb{C})$, and the transformation $T$ induced by the linear transformation given by the matrix:$ A =
    \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 2  \\
    2 & 1  \\
    \end{bmatrix}
$, if I didn't make a mistake, this is precisely a projective variety and a coordinate transformation with $T(V) \neq V$.

[image]

I appreciate any help and thank you all in advance :)

Comment: This means that for any $V \subset \mathbb{P}^n(L)$ and any coordinate transformation $T$ with coefficients in $K$, $V$ is a projective algebraic $K$-variety iff $T(V)$ is a projective algebraic $K$-variety.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I appreciate the help